# How to trigger focus event on input without ref in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have something like this:

```
<App>
    <CommentForm/>
    <CommentList/>
</App>
```

`<App>` has shared `state`s for `<CommentForm/>` and `<CommentList/>`.

`<CommentForm/>` has form and after comment is submitted it appears in `<CommentList>`.

It all works fine expect that I cannot find good way of triggering `focus()` event on `textarea` in `<CommentForm>`.

I know that I can do it by creating ref, but as I known it is not really a good practice.

Is there a way to trigger `focus` event using `state` in React?

Btw, I am not interested in `autoFocus`.

Comment: In the [When to Use Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs) section of the react docs, the 1st line starts with "Managing focus". Don't use refs to get the data from forms, or change styles, but focus is fine.

Comment: @OriDrori is it really the only best practice-like option?

Comment: a ref is not a bad practice. It is a very powerful tool when used correctly. But that being said when something is created (ref in this instance) it gets used in ways that is not intended (like applying styles or getting data out of a form). However focus is a great example of when to use a ref.

Comment: It's actually the only react way to set focus.

Comment: there is `onFocus` Synthetic event in react. here is link to react [docs]: [https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#focus-events]

Answer (score 2):

If you have an id set to your input component you can do the following:

```
document.getElementById('yourInputId').focus();
```

Even though you can use this code I recommend you to use refs instead due to reusability.

You can check a few more info on this post:
https://www.javascriptstuff.com/use-refs-not-ids/